# Multiple events for Docusign embedded ReturnURL

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to set multiple returnUrl's to redirect given the different event outcomes. I am embedding the document. I am using this block of code:

```
"returnUrl" => "http://localhost/docusign/thank-you?event=signing_complete"
```

I've tried to add multiple returnUrl's, but that returns the last one in the array (for example, decline), even when the event=signing_complete.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't believe `?event=signing_complete` should be included in the `returnUrl` that we pass to DocuSign. DocuSign will append that for us - based on whether the recipient signs, declines, just stops for now, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Envelope Level:

If you are setting landing pages for just an envelope, you're going to have to redirect to your site and handle the "multiple redirects" from there with the *event* url paramater.

Quick Sample Redirect Page in PHP/JS:

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['event'])){
  if($_GET['event']=='decline')
    $link = 'www.companysite.com';
  else
    $link = 'www.companysite.com/default';
}else{
  $link = 'www.google.com';
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location.href='<?echo $link;?>'</script>
```

### Account Level:

You can set in-session landing pages in **Preferences > Features > In session landing pages**

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you so much. I had no idea that the account level was even an option.